# Warum kriegt z.B. "Student" die Endung "-en" in dem casus obliquus?

Tags: etymology, noun, history, suffix

> der Student, des Studenten

Woher kommt die Endung *-en* bei Wörtern für Personssubstantive lateinischen und griechischen Ursprungs (oder ist das nicht die Regel)? Es geht mir also nicht um die Endung *-en* der schwache Wörter eines Germanischen Ursprungs.

Ich kenne keine solche Endung im (alt-)Niederländischen, und auch nicht in anderen Sprachen. Ist sie altgermanischen Ursprungs? Oder ist sie vielleicht von adjektivischer Natur?

Comment: Meinst du 'des Studenten' (Genitiv) oder 'die Studenten' (Plural)?

Comment: @Iris im Deutschen: Casus obliquus = Genitiv, Dativ & Akkusativ. (https://de.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Obliquus_(Kasus))

Comment: Das Deklinationsschema ist nicht auf Personssubstantive lateinischen und griechischen Ursprungs beschränkt. "Student" und "Bär" haben die gleichen Kasusendungen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Einige Fremdwörter haben sich den heimischen schwachen Substantiven angeschlossen. Warum?

- Die schwachen Substantive sind maskulin und bezeichnen im typischen Fall Personen (oder zumindest Lebewesen). Sie sind seit jeher Teil der deutschen Sprache: ahd. [boto](http://awb.saw-leipzig.de/cgi/WBNetz/wbgui_py?sigle=AWB&lemma=boto) *Bote*, [Franko](http://awb.saw-leipzig.de/cgi/WBNetz/wbgui_py?sigle=AWB&lemma=franko) *Franke*, [haso](http://awb.saw-leipzig.de/cgi/WBNetz/wbgui_py?sigle=AWB&lemma=haso) *Hase*, [hêrro](http://awb.saw-leipzig.de/cgi/WBNetz/wbgui_py?sigle=AWB&lemma=herro) *Herr*.

  <sub>Man beachte allerdings, daß es im Althochdeutschen noch schwache neutrale und feminine Substantive gab und diese nicht ausschließlich oder in erster Linie Personen bezeichneten: [Old High German declension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Old_High_German_declension#The_weak_declension).</sub>
- Substantivierte Adjektive können zu schwachen Substantiven werden, wie etwa bei  [Junge](http://www.woerterbuchnetz.de/DWB?lemma=junge), [Kunde](http://www.woerterbuchnetz.de/DWB?bookref=11,2620,35). Substantivisch heißt es *ein Junge* (schwach); adjektivisch *ein junger [Mann]* (stark).
- Man beachte die (durch [Nebensilbenabschwächung](http://www.sprachlog.de/2009/10/09/mittelhochdeutsch/) entstandene) Endung *-e*. Sie stellt einen Anknüpfungspunkt für maskuline, Personen bezeichnende Substantive dar, die aus der lateinischen 1. Deklination stammen: *collega* "Kollege", *poeta* "Poet". Man stellt die Fremdwörter, die lautlich und von der Bedeutung her zu den heimischen schwachen Substantiven passen, diesen gleich: *Kollege* wie *Bote*, *Poet* wie *Herr* mit [Apokope](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apokope_(Sprachwissenschaft)).
- Wörter wie *Student, Protestant* gehen auf lateinische [Präsenspartizipien](https://www.altphil.uni-freiburg.de/downloads/ppa.pdf) zurück: *studens*,  Pl. *studentes*; *protestans*, Pl. *protestantes*. Als Partizipien flektieren sie wie Adjektive. Hier sehe ich  substantivierte Adjektive wie *Junge, Kunde* als Anküpfungspunkt: aus Adjektiven mit starken und schwachen Formen werden schwache Substantive.

Comment: Thank you, you have cut a likely path.

Answer (score 7):

Für die obliquus-Bildungen im Deutschen gilt die Unterscheidung in starke und schwache/gemischte Deklination. Der Genitiv "des Studenten" ist ein klassisches Beispiel für die schwache Deklination.

Die Wortklassen, die schwach dekliniert werden, haben germanische Stämme, die auf -n endeten (Beispiel "Bär": *berōn*, *bera-*, **beran**)

Mit der Zeit wurden die ursprünglich weiter differenzierten Endungen (z.B. gotisch -in, -an, -on) zu einer reduziert.

Quellen und weiterführende Information:

[Wikipedia-Artikel Deklination](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deutsche_Deklination#Schwache_und_gemischte_Deklination)

[Gotische Grammatik](https://books.google.at/books?id=UUghAAAAQBAJ&pg=PA103&lpg=PA103&dq=gotische%20deklination%20schwach&source=bl&ots=BwhQ0B672j&sig=U3WIFPfsGEZSygW2fWSRx5B0OCQ&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjPqN6O54LRAhXLfRoKHdE6DQEQ6AEIQTAG#v=onepage&q=gotische%20deklination%20schwach&f=false)

In jüngerer Zeit ist ein Trend zur Vereinfachung eingetreten, so geht mittlerweile der Filmtitel "Rückkehr zum Planet<s>en</s> der Affen" als grammatikalisch korrekt durch.

Comment: I'm sorry, I forgot to reply. Thanks for the information! As to those words with Germanic roots, like Bär, I know they have the same endings *now*, but are those endings etymologically related to the ones of the Latinate words? For Latin did not have those endings, nor are they *normal* German endings. How come Student and Bär get to have the same, abnormal, endings?

Comment: The Germanic n-stems originate from the Indo-European n-stems which are also the origin of the Latin consonantic n-stems.But the weak declination became very widespread in German, replacing the original declination e.g. of adjectives when no article is present.