# -n-Deklination für welche Substantive?

Tags: noun, dative, declension

Ich habe zwei Sätze:

1. > Der Revolver gehört dem Polizisten.
2. > Der Rotstift gehört dem Lehrer.

Warum wird im ersten Satz das Wort *Polizist* dekliniert mit der Endung *-en* und in dem zweite Satz nicht?

Comment: Das ist kein Genitiv, sondern Dativ. Und related, if not duplicate: http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/33853/warum-kriegt-z-b-student-die-endung-en-in-dem-casus-obliquus

Answer (score 4):

Die unterschiedliche Deklination der beiden Substantive liegt daran, dass sie verschiedene Bildungsmuster haben, die sich auf verschiedene germanische Deklinationen zurückführen lassen.

*Lehrer* ist eine direkte Substantivierung des Handlenden zum Verb *lehren.* Vergleichbar wären Wörter wie *Seher, Hörer, Täter, Bäcker* und ihre entsprechenden Verben *sehen, hören, tun, backen.* Es handelt sich hierbei durchweg um germanische Erbwörter und ererbte Grammatikkonstruktionen – obwohl die gleiche Substantivierung auch bei neueren Verben durchgeführt werden kann, wie beim *Internetsurfer.*

Aus dem Urgermanischen wurde für diese Substantivklasse die sogenannte *starke* Deklination ererbt; *stark* heißt, dass im Genitiv singular eine andere Endung zu finden ist als im Akkusativ singular, wobei die Genitivendung bei maskulinen Substantiven meist auf *-s* endet.

Das Wort *Polizist* ist nicht von einem Verb abgeleitet (zumindest nicht im Deutschen). Die Wurzel *Polizei* ist ein Fremdwort, das erst nach der hochdeutschen Lautverschiebung eingedeutscht wurde, und die Endung *-ist* erscheint mir anhand der auf Wikipedia gegebenen Beispiele ebenfalls eine etymologisch jüngere zu sein *(Prokurist, Anarchist,* …). Durchweg werden Wörter, die auf das Suffix *-ist* enden, jedoch *schwach* dekliniert; in der Regel heißt das, dass in allen Fällen außer dem Nominativ ein *-en* oder vergleichbares angehängt wird.

Es gibt zwar einige Tendenzen, welche Ablaute zu welchem Deklinationstyp gehören – zum Beispiel zeigt eine Stammendung aus der Gruppe *-er, -el, -en* in der Regel eine starke Deklination an – doch auch immer wieder Ausnahmen.

Answer (score 2):

Wie Tofro in seinem Kommentar schon sagte, das ist Dativ, nicht Genitiv. Und die Endungen sind verschieden, weil die Substantive Lehrer und Polizist zu Unterschiedlichen Stämmen gehören.

Hift dieser Link zum Thema ["Deutsche Deklination"](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deutsche_Deklination)?