# "nach dem Agenten" or "nach dem Agent", declension for singular masculine dative case?

Tags: dative, declension, grammatical-number, grammar-identification

Original phrase is

> Such in der Stadt **nach *dem Agenten*** namens Hendrik.

Hendrik is surely 1 guy and that means this is singular, so why not :

> Such in der Stadt **nach *dem Agent*** namens Hendrik.

Is this an exception or just a mistake?

Comment: *Dem Agenten* is dative singular. Dative plural would be **den Agenten**. (and yes, the latter is indistiguishable from accusative singular.)

Comment: But isn't the noun "der Agent"?

Comment: Nouns change with case. It's (nom sg) der Agent, (gen sg) des Agenten, (dat sg) dem Agenten, (akk sg) den Agenten, (nom pl) die Agenten, (gen pl) der Agenten, (dat pl) den Agenten, (akk pl) die Agenten. The pattern of this change mostly depends on noun gender. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/German_declension

Comment: related: http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/34150/n-deklination-für-welche-substantive

Comment: This is all correct. Let me add that 'nach dem Agent' is technically wrong but nevertheless used in spoken language.

Comment: I would declare this as a bit of a stylistic special case. Though I can't explain what is correct and why (even as a German, which is funny), both versions are valid in this context and are fully understood.

Comment: Ask a dictionary: https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Agent

Answer (score 2):

"Agent" has to be declined according to the "n-Deklination". All masculine nouns with the ending "-ent" behave like that. Other endings which indicate the "n-Deklination" are: -e, -or, -ant, -oge, -at, -ad and -ist. Very important other examples would be "der Name", "der Kollege", "der Präsident", "der Egoist", ...

These nouns get the ending "-n" in the plural and in the genitive, dative, accusative singular.
- Mein Name ist... / Ich habe einen langen Namen. 
- Das ist mein Kollege. / Ich habe einen netten Kollegen.
- Trump ist Präsident. / Ich sehe den amerikanischen Präsidenten.